# MGSplitViewController not as RootView but within a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitview

I'm very new to iOS programming (Coming from Java / C++). I'm trying to set up an app with a TabBarController of which one tab should be a SplitView. I've done my research and I know that UISplitview will not work and everywhere people recommend using the MGSplitViewController. I've looked at the demo but I just can't figure out how to use it without it beeing the app's root view and can't find any sample code that could help
So here is what I do with the classes from the demo in a separate UIViewController class that I afterwards add to the TabBarController: This is my class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MGSplitCornersView.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"



@interface ChannelViewController : UIViewController {
    MGSplitViewController *splitViewController;
    RootViewController *rootViewController;
    DetailViewController *detailViewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MGSplitViewController *splitViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *rootViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailViewController *detailViewController;


@end
```

And this is my desperate try to set it up

```
- (id)initWithTabBar
{
    self = [super init];

    //this is the label on the tab button itself
    self.title = @"SplitView";

    //use whatever image you want and add it to your project
    //self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name_gray.png"];

    // set the long name shown in the navigation bar at the top
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Nav Title";

    self.splitViewController = [[MGSplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    [self.splitViewController setDetailViewController:detailViewController];
    [self.splitViewController setMasterViewController:rootViewController];

    [self.view addSubview:splitViewController.view];

    [self.rootViewController performSelector:@selector(selectFirstRow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    [self.detailViewController performSelector:@selector(configureView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

    if (NO) { // whether to allow dragging the divider to move the split.
    splitViewController.splitWidth = 15.0; // make it wide enough to actually drag!
    splitViewController.allowsDraggingDivider = YES;
    }

    return self;
}
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with delegates? Or do I have something else mixed up?
Is the demo doing things in the IB that I can't see in the code?
I get the split view but no content and especially no navigation bar with the buttons the demo comes with.

I'd be very thankful for hints or sample code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok manny, here we go. This is my working code for the interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MGSplitViewController.h"
#import "ecbView.h"
#import "ecbCalc.h"

@interface splitMain : MGSplitViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate,
                                              MGSplitViewControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIPopoverController*       popoverController;
    IBOutlet UINavigationController*    naviController;
    IBOutlet ecbCalc*                   viewCalcLeft;
    IBOutlet ecbView*                   euroRatesRight;
             UIBarButtonItem*           savedButtonItem;
             BOOL                       keepMasterInPortraitMode;
             BOOL                       memoryWasDropped;
             BOOL                       viewLoaded;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController* popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController* naviController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ecbCalc* viewCalcLeft;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ecbView* euroRatesRight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem* savedButtonItem;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL keepMasterInPortraitMode;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL memoryWasDropped;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL viewLoaded;

- (void)dismissPopoverController: (BOOL)animated;
- (void)settingsChanged;

@end
```

and here excerpts from implementation file:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
    {
        // my initialization...
    }

    return self;
}

// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect  rectFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 768.0, 1004.0 - 48.0);    // being above a tab bar!

    viewLoaded     = NO;
    self.view      = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rectFrame];
    viewCalcLeft   = [[ecbCalc alloc] initWithNibName:@"ecbCalc" bundle:nil];
    euroRatesRight = [[ecbView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ecbView-iPad" bundle:nil];
    naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewCalcLeft];
    naviController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    naviController.title = nil;
    viewCalcLeft.title   = NSLocalizedString(@"BtnTitleCalc",  @"");
    viewCalcLeft.view.hidden = NO;

    NSUserDefaults* prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"iPadAlwaysSplitTableView"] != nil)
        self.keepMasterInPortraitMode = [prefs boolForKey:@"iPadAlwaysSplitTableView"];
    else
        self.keepMasterInPortraitMode = YES;

    NSArray*    theViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.naviController, self.euroRatesRight, nil];

    [self setViewControllers:theViewControllers];
    [self setDelegate:self];
    [self setShowsMasterInPortrait:keepMasterInPortraitMode];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // protection because this one is called twice
    if (viewLoaded)
        return;

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (memoryWasDropped)
    {
        if (!self.keepMasterInPortraitMode && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
        {
            // recreate popover controller
            self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.viewCalcLeft];
        }
    }

    viewLoaded = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    memoryWasDropped = YES;

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    [self dismissPopoverController:NO];

    self.popoverController = nil;
    self.naviController    = nil;
    self.viewCalcLeft      = nil;
    self.euroRatesRight    = nil;
    viewLoaded = NO;
}
```

My MainWindow.xib has a UITabBarController and the button for splitMain is configured for this class but with an empty xib entry. So creation has to go via loadView. Maybe I could have done the viewDidLoad stuff within loadView ... but so I had to protect viewDidLoad from being called twice. That happens in loadView as soon as the view is instantiated from MGSplitViewController class because the initWithCoder there is calling *[self setup]*. In that function the frame rect is calculated with self.view.bounds so that viewDidLoad is called again because the view doesn't exist yet. Maybe one could implement a workaround within MGSplitViewController.m but I was too lazy doing that.

To get this working on a tab bar controller please make sure you commit most of the changes that are published on the MGSplitViewController's git page. Good luck.

Comment: i implemented d same code., d Splitview is not getting loaded, app getting crashed. in -(void)loadview its showing breakpoint at: left.view.hidden = NO; and also in [SplitViewController setup] its showing breakpoint in CGRect divRect = self.view.bounds;  #pls help.