# iOS iPad - No communication between master- and detailview mgsplitviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I am using `MGSplitViewController` inside a `UIViewController` (i already have a `MGSplitViewController` as `RootViewController` and I use the second one inside the `DetailViewController`).

[Konrans solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039629/mgsplitviewcontroller-not-as-rootview-but-within-a-uiviewcontroller) works perfectly fine (I adopted exactly the code he provided) - except for the fact, that my `MasterView` can not control anything inside the `DetailView`. Is there anything I am missing? I made the connections in IB based on the connections from the `MGSplitViewController` example.

Has anyone come across a similar problem?

Comment: Matt, are you working on iOS 5? I'm currently having also problems on iPad with that since I moved to Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 (2 days ago) because I upgraded my iPad 1 to iOS 5.0.1 and can't use Xcode 3 anymore with it. My UIButtons are not responding in master and detail while the same controller works on iPhone w/out splitting controllers.

Comment: Can you provide more details for what you've used IB? It doesn't work with IB for the MGSplitViewController. Only the master and detail controllers can be supported by IB.

Comment: yes, I figured that out just a minute ago, sorry. But even without IB (my splitviewController still got one xib with a view) it does not work. This is how I try to set the detailView from within the masterView: <!-- language: c# --> { - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    detailView = [[SettingsDetailView alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    detailViewController.view = detailView.view;
    [detailView release];
}}

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your loadView method in your MGSplitViewController's derivate. Normally both detail and master controllers are instantiated there.

When you allocate a detail view controller later again you might come into the situation that the original instance is not released properly and you'll be running with two instances of it.
In this case the master doesn't have access to the new instance.

I had such problems in the very beginning when I used the MGSplitViewController.

You will also step into this problem when you activate a memory warning.

Comment: I will try that, thank you!

Do you think it might be a problem, that there are two MGSplitViewControllers being instantiated? One as root and one inside the detail from the first one itself.

Comment: Maybe - at least the xib things will get complicated and you have to adapt some code w/in MGSplitViewController itself ... those places where UITabBarCtrl and UINavigationController are treated as parent for layout control. My app has 2 splitters placed as 2 different tabs in a UITabBarCtrl. It works, but not 100% because of layout issues. I don't know yet if I have to redesign ;-(
Anyway I don't run exactly into your problem.

Comment: Yes I am still wondering whether I have to disable some Orientations, because they are causing some trouble, too. So the redesign thing is also in my head...

I deleted every xib except for the master and detail ones - and there is no problem. I found out that my detailView is allocated but it seems like it is not retained properly, as in my master controller I try to access my detailView and the pointer reads 0x0 - now I stripped down the code of my SplitViewController to match exactly yours and there is still no way to access the detail :-/

Comment: SOLVED!

I simply told my master when I instantiated it (inside the SplitViewController), who is his detail:

masterViewController.detailView = self.detailViewController;

Comment: Great! ... and it's really working everything? I'm asking because I've got problems with the MGSplitViewController on iOS 5 that I had not with iOS 4. Buttons in a subcontroller don't work.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine! In iOS 5. You can access everything inside the detail - Buttons, Tables, everything, did you try my solution? But I am running into another problem now - when I try to change my main detail from within the rootMaster (the outer one), I only get a black screen in my detail. So I have to do some research on that.

Comment: I did not try your solution because it's not a matter of inter-accessing the controllers. A custom keypad doesn't work - no matter if it is placed as master or via navigation controller in detail view. Maybe it's better to go for the standard iOS splitter in iOS 5. The MGSplitViewController isn't maintained for ... years or so.