# Issue with Pushing MGSplitViewController onto a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a requirement to push a `UISplitViewController` onto a `UINavigationController`. After doing lots of research, I found out that a general SplitView must be the root view of the application.

I later found [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) on github. To accomplish my requirement I followed [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039629/mgsplitviewcontroller-not-as-rootview-but-within-a-uiviewcontroller).

After all these its not working and the app is crashing with a breakpoint. Can anyone shed some light on this.

EDIT:
[image]

[Bigger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jl9N.png)

Comment: what do you mean with *getting crashed with Break-point*?

Comment: @tkanzakic Pls check..

Comment: Are you sure LeftViewController has called `viewDidLoad` before you set `left.view.hidden = NO`?

Comment: @hellozimi No, LeftViewController's `viewDidLoad` is not executed before `left.view.hidden = NO `